# “ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset” error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, server

I am failing to establish a ssh connection via password with a server.

```
C:\Users\hoyong>ssh username@SERVER_IP_ADDRESS
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset
```

It is confusing, because it works fine with some clients connected to a different network.
(There are no rules in server-side /etc/hosts.deny or /etc/hosts.allow.) 
(doesn't seem to be a problem with IPTABLES. IPTABLE rules are as follows.)

```
(base) name@server:/$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

What might be the problem?

Here's the verbose debug info. of ssh connection trial on client-side.

```
C:\Users\hoyong>ssh -vvv username@SERVER_IP_ADDRESS
OpenSSH_for_Windows_7.7p1, LibreSSL 2.6.5
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname SERVER_IP_ADDRESS is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to SERVER_IP_ADDRESS [SERVER_IP_ADDRESS] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_rsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_rsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_rsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_rsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_dsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_dsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_dsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_dsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_ecdsa error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_ed25519 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_xmss error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_xmss.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_xmss-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/hoyong/.ssh/id_xmss-cert.pub error:2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\hoyong/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug3: send - WSASend() ERROR:10054, io:0000017EE48EFA70
write: Connection reset
```

The server-side /var/log/auth.log looks like this

```
May 28 20:46:20 server01 sshd[29836]: Connection reset by CLIENT_IP_ADDRESS port 7768 [preauth]
```

Comment: From the debug output it appears you've got no `rsa` or `dsa` ID files.  Not sure this will help for your connection, try running `ssh-keygen -t rsa` (maybe `dsa` as well), then retry your `ssh` cmd-line.  Any better results?

Comment: Try to run another instance of sshd in debug mode on port 222 and test from your local machine.

Comment: @Milag generated public and private keys, but same error rises.     

"debug3: send - WSASend() ERROR:10054, io:000001860B8E6400
write: Connection reset"

Answer (score 0):

Delete the file named 'known_hosts' which are in '.ssh' folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).